# uTorrent download limit cancels transmissions

Tags: windows-7, download, hibernate, utorrent

I have the latest uTorrent (v3.3.2) on Windows 7 64-bit.

I've been noticing lately that when I set a global download limit of any kind, uTorrent will stop downloading and uploading completely. It's only when I set the download limit to "Unlimited", it starts working again. This happens for torrents from different trackers.

Restarting uTorrent fixes this until the next time my PC wakes up from hibernation.

This was working fine for the past 5 months, I'm not sure what's changed that could have caused this? Does anyone else have these problems? How did you fix them?

**EDIT:** I now have v3.4.2 and I'm still having this problem. Seeing how another user have the same problem, maybe I should officially report a bug.

**EDIT 2:** I have since switched to Deluge. I find it a better fit for my usage.

Comment: download 3.3 and see if it does the same thing, because mine works fine.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with uTorrent 3.4.2 on Windows 8

Comment: Same issue. Version 3.4.5 build 41712

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this somewhere else, credits to Kewlx25

"Options -> Preferences -> Bandwidth -> untick 'Apply rate limit to transport overhead'"

That fixed it for me.

Best of lucks.